# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-BsCvtg/matplotlib

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to install packages(like matplotlib, numpy) using pip on centos, I got an error, I've installed python-devel, openssl-devel, and I've already updated pip and setuptools(33.1.1 or 40.0.2). python version is 2.7.15. error info is long, pls be patient, thank you very much

```
Collecting matplotlib
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Running from numpy source directory.
    /tmp/easy_install-WPJbWM/numpy-1.15.1/setup.py:378: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    /tmp/easy_install-WPJbWM/numpy-1.15.1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    /bin/sh: svnversion: command not found
    /bin/sh: svnversion: command not found
    /home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [2.2.3]
                    python: yes [2.7.15 (default, Nov 13 2018, 11:55:34)  [GCC
                            3.4.5 20051201 (Red Hat 3.4.5-2)]]
                  platform: yes [linux2]
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'exp' [enabled by default]
     int exp (void);
         ^
    _configtest.o: In function `main':
    /tmp/easy_install-WPJbWM/numpy-1.15.1/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    xxxx
    _configtest.o: In function `main':
    /tmp/easy_install-WPJbWM/numpy-1.15.1/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    xxxx
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'exp' [enabled by default]
     int exp (void);
         ^
    _configtest.c:3:1: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
     main()
     ^
    File: build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/_numpyconfig.h
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.swp' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bak' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
    numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c.src: In function 'npy_casinhf':
                                       ^
    /home/work/gcc/opt/binutils/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/liblapack.so when searching for -llapack
    /home/work/gcc/opt/binutils/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
    /home/work/gcc/opt/binutils/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
    /home/work/gcc/opt/binutils/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/liblapack.so when searching for -llapack
    /home/work/gcc/opt/binutils/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libm.so when searching for -lm
    /home/work/gcc/opt/binutils/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.a when searching for -lc
    /home/work/gcc/opt/binutils/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a when searching for libc_nonshared.a
    xxxx
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-j9VASQ/matplotlib/setup.py", line 278, in <module>
        **extra_args
      File "/home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 139, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 134, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 514, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 777, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1060, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1072, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 581, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 676, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 702, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 887, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1155, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/home/work/xxxx/app/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1143, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Command "/home/work/gcc/opt/gcc48/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/python_xerbla.o -L/usr/lib -L/home/work/gcc/opt/gcc48/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.3/../../../../lib64 -L/home/work/gcc/opt/gcc48/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.3/../../../../lib64 -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -llapack -llapack -lblas -lblas -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so" failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-j9VASQ/matplotlib/
```

thank you very much

Comment: which version of matplotlib you are trying to install? Matplotlib 3.0 is Python 3 only. For Python 2 support, Matplotlib 2.2.x.

Comment: 2.2.3, python version is 2.7.15

Comment: output: gcc: error: _configtest.o: No such file or directory, gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.